# Is there an easy way to selecting multiple criteria in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if a cell is equal to some elements, like the example below.

```
If Range("A1") = "Element1" Or Range("A1") = "Element2" Or Range("A1") = "Element3" Or Range("A1") = "Element4" Or Range("A1") = "Element5" Then 
 'Do the code
End if
```

I think this way is a little confusion to read, especially because the real code that I'm making will have 35 elements.

I know that in MySql can use the command IN like the example below.

```
subject IN ('Cookery','Chemistry','Literature')
```

Is there something like that in vba?

Comment: You can use `Select Case Range("A1")` , and underneath have `Case "Element1" , "Element2", etc...`

Comment: Thanks @ShaiRado it works like I want. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Case` switch is probably best-suited for this:

```
Select Case Range("A1").Value
    Case "Element1", "Element2", "Element3", "Element4", "Element5"
        'Do stuff

    Case Else
         'Do other stuff, or do nothing at all

End Select
```

Note that the above is case-sensitive. If you have mixed-case and don't care about capitalization, convert to a single case using the `LCASE` or `UCASE` function:

```
Select Case LCase(Range("A1").Value))
    Case "element1","element2","element3","element4","element5"
```

Alternatively, you can use the filter function on a vector array:

```
Const Elements As String = "element1,element2,element3,element4,element5"
Dim val$, myArray
myArray = Split(Elements, ",")
val = "element3"

    If UBound(Filter(myArray, val)) >= 0 Then
        'the value is in the array
        MsgBox True
    Else
        'the value is not in the array
        MsgBox False
    End If
```

There are some quirks with the `Filter` function though, and I think it is not always 100% reliable since it will return partial matches.

Or you can use the `Match` function against an array:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(val, myArray, False)) Then
    'value exist in the list
Else
    'value does not exist in the list
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot David.

Comment: Another example of `Case` could be `Select Case Val(Replace(Sheet1.Range("A1"), "Element", ""))`.  You could then use `Case 1 To 35` - or `Case 1 To 10`, `Case 11 To 20`, etc.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook yeah that's an awesome hack for sure! I was thinking to elaborate with some more string examples but didn't want to make the answer too complicated. I do like that solution of yours though, very clean!